# Object of another class in another class member function

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A();

private:
    void slot();
};
```

The second class B looks like:

```
class B
{
public:
    B();

private:
    // Some stuff...
};
```

In file1.cpp there are static objects of both classes:

```
static A a;
static B b;
```

Now in file2.cpp(containing the class implementation) I would need in the slot function of `class A` the object `b`, which was created in file1.cpp. What is the best way to get it?
How is this done using C++?

Comment: Are those static objects at file/namespace scope or class scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` means "local to this translation unit". What you are trying to do is impossible.

An alternative design would use non-static namespace scope objects, like:

globals.hpp:

```
extern A a;
extern B b;
```

globals.cpp:

```
#include "globals.hpp"
A a;
B b;
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "globals.hpp"
void A::slot(){
    //use b
}
```

You need to be careful with this design to ensure that you do not call `A::slot` before `b` has been constructed.

Comment: Thx for your answer. But is it not possible to use some setters/getters and keep the objects static instead of declaring them as extern?